# Attack of the Asthmatic Enemy Omnivores

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, anagram

You're under attack! Who by, you may ask? By the Asthmatic Enemy Omnivores, of course! Why? Irrelevant!

You've just found a bomb that they planted near your headquarters, and the only way to disarm it is to put in the correct six letter code. The only hints are a cryptic poem (with horrible meter and slant rhyming), and an image with a large array of letters in red, green, and yellow. The image also has what appears to be some guides, but otherwise it is rather unclear what's going on.

> Before you proceed, it seems you must find
>   A background image, to match with the lines.
>
> Then take the letters, that blend in right
>   And order them round, from naught to two-pi

[image: Where have I seen these colors before?]
<sup>(Click to enlarge/download. You'll probably need to!)</sup>

Comment: As a point of interest;  the personages in this puzzle are the Asthmatic Enemy Omnivores, You, and (from the point of view of the puzzle text) @DqwertyC is implicitly "I".  And the only question explicitly asked is "Why?".  Yay for secret vowel puzzles!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we

> overlay the PSE logo so that some of its pointy angular bits match the guides, we get this:
>  [image]

and hence, following instructions

> by reading letters that match their local background colour, anticlockwise from the east, NOW YOU MUST AGAIN GO ROUND THIS TIME READING RED ON GREEN. (These letters are the ones I have circled in the unreadable image above.)

This in turn yields

> by reading in the same order but looking only at red letters on green background, NOW LOOK AGAIN FROM BASE TO TOP READING SUN WITHIN THE VOID which I take means yellow on not-part-of-the-logo (the other obvious interpretation is yellow on black, but there isn't enough black).

This yields

> LAST STEP NOW FROM CENTER OUT EVERY GREEN STILL UNUSED

and *this* yields

> (with some pain because distance to centre is not so visually apparent as one might like) ITS SO META EVEN THIS ACRONYM

so the required 6-letter code is clearly

> ISMETA (see [here](https://xkcd.com/917/) for background).

Credit where it's due: ffao posted a partial answer before I posted anything, but on my honour (should I happen to have any) I declare that I had already got further than that when he posted it :-).

Comment: As always, I am amazed by how fast you can solve these! Fun fact, the "Asthmatic Enemy Omnivores" is an anagram for the second-to-last step.

Comment: I expected you to have gotten further than I did; you didn't have to waste time composing an answer, for one. But using transparency this way looks much smarter than what I did too.

Answer (score 4):

**Partial answer**

The image has some suspicious looking guides, looks like three right corners but they do not line up to form a rectangle. Where have I seen something like this?

> The Puzzling logo! (I guess "red, green and yellow" was a hint to this too, but I only realized after I'd found the correct image.)
>  [image]

Following the poem, let's overlap the background image with the lines:

> I also only left the letters that matched the color of their corresponding region, because we should take "the letters that blend in":
>
>   [image]

Reading from 0 to 2-pi (aka start from right, read counter-clockwise):

> "NOW AGAIN YOU MUST GO ROUND THIS TIME READING RED OR GREEN" [edit: possibly RED ON GREEN?]
>
>  I believe this is telling us to ignore yellow, but reading the same way doesn't give me a coherent message, assuming I did it right.

Comment: Bah! I was waiting until I'd finished all the steps before posting anything...

Comment: Feel free to finish it up, @Gareth, I just didn't want all this painstaking work to go to waste ;)